# How can I post JSON with PHP and curl?

Tags: php, curl

I managed to get my request working in "Advanced Rest Client" using the following settings:

[image]

However, I tried to recreate the same request using PHP and I can't work out what I'm doing wrong. Here's what I have:

```
$config['key'] = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
$config['clientid'] = xxxxxxxxx;

$url = 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.curdbee.com/invoices.json?api_token='.$config['key'];

$data = Array();  
$data['invoice']['client_id'] = $config['clientid'];

$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   

$ch = curl_init($url);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo curl_error($ch);

print_r($result);
```

Neither $result nor curl_error outputs anything and I can't work out why.

Comment: maybe add cookie accept to json and also more headers like browser. Check the whole raw http request and see details of it.

Comment: what is the result of var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));

Comment: @Pattle http://pastebin.com/yKrithcS

Comment: @Robert I tried setting all the headers shown in "Advanced Rest Client" but I'm still getting nothing. The raw http request is just the URL + the api key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to add these two lines:

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);
```